# How get old Apple bluetooth keyboard and mouse recognised

Tags: bluetooth, peripherals

I have an old Apple Bluetooth keyboard and mouse from about 12 years ago. They can still connect to my newer Mac laptop, but the Pi 3 bluetooth adaptor cannot see them at all. According to Apple's Bluetooth Explorer utility, the mouse and keyboard both support Bluetooth Core Spec 1.1.

Is there a way to get the Pi to see these peripherals, perhaps by adding extra Bluetooth 1.1 support to the Pi?

Comment: You may need to disconnect from the Mac first. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237806/19086 which may help

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Milliways, but I'd already done that without success. The Pi isn't seeing them at all.